# Clearing Session data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In my view I have a button using simple_form gem:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(:place_order, :url => "#{}", html: {id: "place_order" }) do |f|  %>
    <%= f.button :button, "Clear Cart", class: "btn btn-primary clearcart", id: "clear_cart", name: "clear_cart" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Continue Shopping", class: "btn btn-success contShop", id: "continue_shopping", name: "continue_shopping" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Proceed to Checkout", class: "btn btn-danger checkout", id: "proceed_to_checkout", name: "proceed_to_checkout" %>
  <% end %>
```

My CoffeeScript is as follows:

```
jQuery ->
  $('button#clear_cart.btn.btn.btn-primary.clearcart').on 'click', (event) ->
    $.post '/shopping/clear_cart'
  $('input#continue_shopping.btn.btn-success.contShop').on 'click', (event) ->
    $('#place_order').attr 'action', '/shopping'
  $('input#proceed_to_checkout.btn.btn-danger.checkout').on 'click', (event) ->
    $('#place_order').attr 'action', '/shopping/place_order'
  $('input#place_an_inquiry.btn.btn-danger.checkout').on 'click', (event) ->
    $('#place_order').attr 'action', '/shopping/review_order'
```

My clear_cart action from the controller is as follows:

```
def clear_cart
  session[:product_quantity] = nil
  redirect_to shopping_index_path
end
```

Clicking on the clear_cart button I a JavaScript error where clear_cart action is not available where as I have already added it in the route file.

```
  resources :shopping, :only => [:index] do
    collection do
      .....
      get   :clear_cart
      post  :clear_cart
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong here that it is not clearing the session data and return me to correct area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments to [nesiseka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3243794/nesiseka) i was not able to make it work the way he suggested so I went ahead with the following solution.

Controller:

```
def clear_cart
  session.delete(:product_quantity)
  if request.post?
    redirect_to shopping_index_path
  end
end
```

view:

```
    <%= simple_form_for(:place_order, :url => "#{}", html: {id: "place_order" }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Clear Cart", class: "btn btn-primary clearcart", id: "clear_cart", name: "clear_cart" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Continue Shopping", class: "btn btn-success contShop", id: "continue_shopping", name: "continue_shopping" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Proceed to Checkout", class: "btn btn-danger checkout", id: "proceed_to_checkout", name: "proceed_to_checkout" %>
    <% end %>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
  $('input#clear_cart.btn.btn-primary.clearcart').on 'click', (event) ->
    $('#place_order').attr 'action', '/shopping/clear_cart'
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way you're going it looks like you should let the rails do the clearing and redirect via JS instead.

I'd go for something like:

routes

```
resources :shopping, :only => [:index] do
  collection do
    .....
    post  :clear_cart
  end
end
```

controller

```
def clear_cart
  session.delete(:product_quantity)
  render json: {success: true, url: shopping_index_path}
end
```

js

```
$('button#clear_cart.btn.btn.btn-primary.clearcart').on 'click',    (event) ->
  $.post '/shopping/clear_cart'.success(response) ->
    window.location = response.url
```

Comment: getting ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: It seems I am not able to get or post the clear_cart action. When it hit it directly, it does return data but when I try and access it via CoffeeScript, I am getting error. Not sure what can be causing this.

Comment: You should add a respond_to block to your controller:

    def clear_cart
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
          session.delete(:product_quantity)
          render json: {success: true, url: shopping_index_path}
        }
    end

Comment: For whatsoever reason i was not able to get the JS to be able to access the action. It think it has something to do with one of the gems I am using.